# Дан массив целых чисел A. Требуется найти число различных сумм, составленных из части его элементов

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, динамическое-программирование

Дан массив целых чисел A. Требуется найти число различных сумм, составленных из части его элементов. Для массива [1,2,3] полный набор сумм — это [0, 1, 1+2, 1+3, 1+2+3, 2, 2+3, 3]. Различные суммы — это {0,1,2,3,4,5,6}. Итого 7 различных сумм.
Ограничения: длина массива A не превышает 500, его элементы принимают значения от 0 до 100.
Мой код:

```
def combinations(iterable, r):
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(r))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)

def sums(array: list) -> int:
    combs = []

    for i in range(2, len(array)+1):
        combs += list(combinations(array, i))

    sumsSet = set([0] + array + list(map(sum, combs)))

    return len(sumsSet)

print(sums([49, 100, 98, 49, 0]))
```

Для коротких входных массивов алгоритм работает быстро, а для больших, к примеру: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64] + [100] * 493 выполняется очень долго. Как я могу сократить время выполнения алгоритма?

Comment: Если у вас 500 элементов, сколько будет комбинаций для которых надо сосчитать суммы?

Comment: Пусть вы научились решать задачу для набора из 99 элементов и знаете множество сумм для них. Как решить задачу для 100 элементов?

Comment: Разделяй и властвуй?

Comment: Как устроена сумма для 100 элементов? Это или сумма для 99 элементов или сумма для 99 элементов плюс что?

Comment: сумма для 99 элементов + 100-й элемент

Comment: Теперь задайте сумму для нуля элементов и программируйте решение.

Comment: Какое самое толстое множество можно получить если 500 штук от нуля до ста?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот такое скорее всего нужно?

```
array = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64] + [100] * 493

res = {0}

for num in array:
    res = set(list(res) + [(i + num) for i in res])

print(len(res))
```

или так:

```
res = {0}

for num in array:
    res.update([(i + num) for i in res])
```